# How can I alleviate intermittent freezes?

Tags: technical-issues, amnesia-a-machine-for-pigs

While playing the game mostly everything goes smoothly except for one thing, intermittent freezing. Every so often (pretty much at random) the game will stutter, and by that I mean it will freeze then quickly go to where it should be. If you've ever played a game like Amnesia: The Dark Descent or any of the Penumbra games you probably know that the atmosphere is amazing, but this stuttering really makes the game hard to enjoy (it's still enjoyable, but not quite as much with the frequent stuttering/lag/freezing temporarily).

Things I've tried, but didn't help:

- Lowering my settings (both custom and the presets) to see if it was my system.
- Modify my main configuration file (one of the developers/administrators recommended trying it). See his post below:
  [image: jens_post]([Original Post](http://www.frictionalgames.com/forum/thread-22916-post-257263.html#pid257263))
- Update drivers (stable and beta version).
- Close all unnecessary background programs.

[This is not an isolated incident other people on Frictional Games forums](http://www.frictionalgames.com/forum/thread-22916.html) say that they have nearly the same or similar problem. So, does anyone have any ideas/suggestions on how I can try and fix this or at least make it more *playable*?

My system specs are:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64bits
- AMD Phenom II X4 955 @3.20GHz
- 8GB DDR3
- Nvidia GeForce GT430 1GB

Comment: Do you have a single GPU or multiple GPUs? More generally, what are your components?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Single GPU I think. My specifications can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/j6LFHvXF). Despite the fact my computer is not aging well at all, I should still be able to run AAMFP reasonably well at medium to low settings.

Comment: Have you checked to see what else is running on your machine in the background (Virus Scan, Windows Updates, etc)? Have you checked your computer's error log (Event Viewer on Windows) to see if anything is going on? I've had problems with a game freezing because it was trying to write to my Hard Drive which was failing and taking a long time.

Comment: @SimonL Come to think of it I actually stopped the Windows Update service last night, because I was sick of the nag message (asking me to restart or postpone) using "NET STOP "windows update"". Could a pending restart cause any problems? I'm not sure. Also how could I log my hardrive read/write history from a game?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'd also like your advice on what I asked above (the comment above) as well, please.

Comment: Sorry, I know not from Windows system administration. I power user a bit, but the black magic of the update system is beyond me.

Comment: Doing some research, I'm going to tentatively point the finger at your GPU: [it's a deliberately cut-down GPU that is heavily handicapped on bandwidth and never intended to be used for gaming](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3973/nvidias-geforce-gt-430). The game's initial, unpatched release probably has performance inefficiencies that are flooding the card's input bandwidth, causing it to be fine until it fills up, stutters long enough to clear the IO backlog, then fills up again. Still, only a guess though.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I understand my GPU is low-end, and really needs a replacement. However others who have much higher end systems still are experiencing problems (freezing/stuttering) so it's the game (as you said). Should I just hope for an update or what else can I do? my laptop has an Intel HD 4000 card and I'm sure as hell that won't fair much better.

Comment: Maybe I should seek a refund? I'm hoping that an update will help performance, but I'm skeptical. Frictional Games has been good to it's users in the past so I guess I'll wait it out.

Comment: You really need to apply your windows updates in a timely manor. It's not worth being compromised because you didn't want to reboot. With that being said, I have seen cases where pending windows updates have caused minor issues. And to answer your question, yes, you can monitor HD activity. Press ctrl + shift + esc then click the performance tab, then the resource monitor button. (bottom section) Click the disk tab. You may need to click the disk activity section to expand it. But from here you can see all the processes writing/reading and even which files are being accessed. Good luck.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_liP41MFXiY might offer a fix, worth a shot.